# Maven Dependency SLF4J Binding with Code Generation

Tags: maven, plugins, code-generation, slf4j, logback

I have maven project (P) with a dependency on another maven built project (G).
This project (G) has a dependency on slf4j and a binding 'logback-classic' (LC).
Project (P) has its own dependency on slf4j but with a binding to 'logback-android-classic' (LAC).
The project (G) is a code generator which is run during phase 'generate-sources'.
How do I cause the classpath for the code generator to include LC and not LAC, but the primary artifact to build with LAC and not LC?

I'm guessing this has something to do with PluginManagement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project G shouldn't be a dependency of P. It's only a plugin, used during the build. It should only be listed in the `<plugins>` section of project P's pom. Its slf4j implementation won't end up on P's classpath.

It sounds like G isn't playing by the rules of a plugin. It should be using Maven's logger, not SLF4J. More here http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-custom-plugin.html